# How to properly use references in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use references in mongoose but somehow am not being able to do it properly.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I would like to query the `examModel` and get all information about a particular exam including the questions related to that exam.

**What I achieved**

New questions get saved into the `questionModel` with the object id of the exam am saving the question for, BUT, the `questions` array of the `examModel` doesnt take notice of it.

I have two different models:

**examModel**

```
const examSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    examId: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        required: true,
        default: _generateAlphanumericId(18),
    },
    questions: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Questions",
    }],
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Exams", examSchema);
```

**questionModel**

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _refExamId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Exams",
    },
    questionId: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        required: true,
        default: _generateAlphanumericId(26),
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, "Question is missing"],
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Questions", questionSchema);
```

Now, when I save a new question into the question model, I am sending the `_id` of an exam from the exam model but still the `questions` array of `exam model` doesnt save the object ids of newly created questions.

**How I am creating a new question**

```
    try {
        const question = new questionModel({ _refExamId: req.body._refExamId, title: req.body.title });
        await question.save();

        return res.status(200).json({ type: "SUCCESS" });
    }
    catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            type: "ERROR",
            message: "Some unknown error occurred",
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
 

        const question = new questionModel({ _refExamId: req.body._refExamId, title: req.body.title });
        const saved_question = await question.save();
        const getExam = await examModel.find({_id: saved_question._refExamId});
        getExam.questions.push(saved_question._id);
        const result = await getExam.save();
                    
        return res.status(200).json({ type: "SUCCESS" });
    }catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
               type: "ERROR",
               message: "Some unknown error occurred",
       });
    }
```

This should get it working.

Comment: Definitely. The `_refExamId` is the object Id from one of the exams that is already present in the `Exam` table.

Comment: So what you want now is that, whenever you create a new question, you want to push the question_id into _refExamId.question array of exam table right?

Comment: According to the docs, it seems I don't need to explicitly push anything except the fact I need to send the object id of the exam into the question schema. But while following the docs, it does not appear to happen so unless I push explicitly to the exam schema

Comment: Exactly that is how it works. Do you need me to send a code sample?

Comment: That is what I was following but it doesnt seem to work that way.

Comment: And also a suggestion, you might want to consider consolidating all your answers into 1 thread and not creating multiple answers.

Comment: Check the code above. I just corrected it. it should work

Comment: Its fine. I sorted it out.

Comment: Yep! thats the way it should be. We both sorted it on the same time

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

**Exam Model**

```
    const examSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        examId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            index: true,
            required: true,
            default: _generateAlphanumericId(18),
        },
        questions: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Question'
        }],
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Exam", examSchema);
```

Note: I turned **Exams** to **Exam**, Mongodb will change it to plural on your DB

**Question Model**

```
 

       const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        _refExamId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Exam",
        },
        questionId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            index: true,
            required: true,
            default: _generateAlphanumericId(26),
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: [true, "Question is missing"],
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
```

Note: I turned **Questions** to **Question**, Mongodb will change it to plural on your DB

Creating a new Question

```
    try {
            const question = new questionModel({ _refExamId: req.body._refExamId, title: req.body.title });
            await question.save();
    
            return res.status(200).json({ type: "SUCCESS" });
        }
        catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                type: "ERROR",
                message: "Some unknown error occurred",
            });
        }
```

Try that and lets see

Comment: Tried. Its still the same. :(

Comment: But is it saving to DB as null or you are getting error? If there is an error, do share with us

Comment: Also comment out req.body._refExamId to be sure that its reaching your API

Comment: The question being saved properly. Just that, the Exam schema's questions array doesnt have any object ids of the questions created.

Comment: And yea no errors, just that the questions array in exams schema stays blank even after adding a question to the question model

Answer (score 0):

So, I was not reading the [refs-to-children](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children) part of the docs where it states that, there will be no references in the parent schema unless we explicitly push the reference to the parent.

As a result the following solved my issue:

```
    try {
        const exam = await examModel.findOne({ examId: req.body.exam_id });
        const question = new questionModel({ title: req.body.title, positiveMarks: req.body.positiveMarks });
        exam.questions.push(question);
        await exam.save(question.save());

        return res.status(200).json({ type: "SUCCESS" });
    }
    catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            type: "ERROR",
            message: "Some unknown error occurred",
        });
    }
```